# Accessing external object from lightning customer community

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-connect

I have an external object that I am trying to access from a customer community page via LWC but it is throwing an exception

**"sObject type 'Customer_Store__x' is not supported.".**

Customer_Store is table in our PGSQL db. I can execute the method from the APEX class from my admin login and it works in developer console.

I have granted read access to this object to the customer community profiles and still no luck.

Can we access external objects from lighting customer communities?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently we need to make the APEX class with "without sharing" explicitly so that it would not enforce sharing rules.

It is working after adding below sharing clause.

```
public without sharing class ExternalUtils {
}
```